# Return results from form as split array

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to customize an existing opensource script and ran into a snag. In the processing file, I'm using the following line to retrieve the user's input from a form they submit.

```
$listingKeywords = $_POST["listingKeywords"];
```

The user is asked in the form to enter the keywords with a comma in between each one (example: Keyword One, Keyword Two). Within the processing file, I have the following...

```
$keyword_list = array(
'1'=>"HTML5",
'2'=>"CSS3",
'3'=>"PHP",
);
```

This is being used later on like so:

```
foreach ($keyword_list as $key=>$value)
```

Basically I'm looking for a way to split $listingKeywords by comma and then set the $key via $i++. I know it's simple and I'm just asking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$arr = explode("," $content);`

is this what you want?

Just remember to use `trim` before putting them into a database, people well tend to do use `value1, value2, value3`

Comment: +, but say it with conviction - *You want `explode()`* :)